# Can I have two different characters with different stats on GTA Online?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-online

I own a copy of GTA V on Steam and I'm very confused because everyone says something different everywhere so I have decided to ask here since R* completely ignored me on their forums.

I would like to create two different characters with everything separate (Stats, Money etc) in GTA Online, is this possible or do I need to buy another copy of GTA V ?

Also is it possible to give each character a new nickname ?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a second character, the bank account, houses and bought clothes are shared. But the stats (driving etc.) and the level is not.

You could create a character with an opposite sex you dont share the clothes.

But if you want your character completely sepperated you have to buy a new copy of GTA 5.

Answer (score 2):

I apparently don't have enough reputation to add a comment to Baumi's answer but character weapon inventory is also separate (a new character was the only way I could get rid of the eight pistols I had acquired over my playtime)

It is possible to give each character a unique nickname but you will still be seen as your rockstar social club name by other players which essentially renders the nickname useless